# Can't update Ubuntu 19.04 due to dependency error. How do I fix this?

Tags: updates, dependencies, 19.04

I am getting this error message:

[image: Software Updater error message]

The message says packages have unmet dependencies, and lists:

```
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386: libglx0:i386: Depends libc6 (>= 2.8) but 2.29-0ubuntu2 is installed
        Depends: libglvnd0 (= 1.1.1-0ubuntu1) but 1.1.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
        Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but 2:1.6.7-1 is installed
libosmesa6:i386: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.2) but 1:9.1.0-2ubuntu2~19.04 is installed
        Depends libglapi-mesa (= 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1) but 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1 is installed
        Depends: libllvvm8 (>= 1:8~svn298832-1~) but 1:8-3 is installed
        Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-1ubuntu2 is installed
```

Comment: So it seems you've been mucking about graphics drivers. What exactly did you do before this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Unmet dependency means that the package attempted to install is looking for dependencies, and the needed version is not found. One way to solve this could be to update the package database, clean out the package cache, and download-and-reinstall the newer version.

Try these commands on terminal (changing the package-name part to packages you see on the "package system is broken window"), one by one and hitting enter on each:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -u dist-upgrade
sudo apt clean package-name
sudo apt install --reinstall package-name
```